# Does Google App Engine Flex support Pipfile?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pipenv, app-engine-flexible

For App Engine Standard the explicitly state that they do not support Pipfiles and immediately block you from pushing your project if it contains a Pipfile. In searching the documentation, I don't see anything that mentions if Pipfile is supported or not for App Engine Flex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just include `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in the `.gcloudignore` file and run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` after any library changes.

Comment: This is the best answer. It should be chosen as correct

Answer (score 2):

App Engine Flexible (and App Engine Standard) do not support `Pipfile`/`Pipfile.lock`.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries says:

> Dependencies for python applications are declared in a standard `requirements.txt` file.

and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies says:

> Dependency specification using the `Pipfile`/`Pipfile.lock` standard is currently not supported and your project must not have these files present.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a few tests, and, while the presence of a `Pipfile` file in the deployment directory of a GAE flexible app does not generate any errors, the file itself is completely ignored, along the dependencies specified in it.

Moreover, when attempting to replace the [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file with the `Pipfile`, a [sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app) Python app deployment in the flexible environment errors out, asking for the `gunicorn` dependency which I had specified in the `Pipfile` instead.

Therefore, the short answer is unfortunately **no, same applies for the flexible environment and thus, dependency specification using the** `Pipfile`/`Pipfile.lock` **standard is not supported at the moment.**