# python appengine Pipfile not supported in the"python37" runtime

Tags: app.yaml

i am getting the following error

```
`INVALID_ARGUMENT: File Pipfile not supported in the"python37" runtime   in "./app.yaml", line 134`.
```

I have tried other solutions that recommend removing Pipfile and replacing it with requirements.txt but they have not worked because the code base does not have a Pipfile to begin with.

Is Pipfile named something else? Maybe I am missing something in the app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
version: 1
default_expration: 7d
auto_id_policy: default
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [App Engine dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies):

> Dependency specification using the `Pipfile/Pipfile.lock` standard is currently not supported and your project must not have these files present.

You can also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546089/does-google-app-engine-flex-support-pipfile) that is related to your question.

Otherwise, it might be picking up a cached previous version of your files and app.yaml. You may try re-deploying while explicitly declaring the modified app.yaml. `$ gcloud app deploy [new_app.yaml]`